# Run A 3 watt LED chip off a 12v Source

Tags: led, integrated-circuit

I have tryed look at other topics on here, but i cant understand what all they are talking about need something simple and to the point please.
So i got thease 3 watt LED chips, Forward V 2.2 And Forward Amps (Current) 700MA
I want to hook this up to a car battery. I tryed a resistor of 15ohm 1/2watt and i dint think about the wattage power coming in effect so it got hot in a hurry.
So a calculator reccomends 7.6 watt capable resistors. There expensive and hard to find and big. Is there any other way to get the voltage and current were i need it? Please use simple terms. Country Boy Here.

Comment: 2.2V 700mA is nowhere near 3W for a start. But the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Maybe worth noting, you also always hook up more LEDs or rectifier diodes in series to drop voltage, if that's an option.

Comment: I would guess the OP meant 3.2V for a white LED, but should clarify. Agree with @tjbtech, 3 3.2V LEDs in series is the way to go if you can.

Comment: Wirewound cermet resistors are available for less than a dollar in the 2-5 W range.

Comment: I have a orange LED the ebay seller said 2.2v. What he said

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you want to use a switching or buck based led driver for this. Or you can use multiple 5W resistors in series/parallel. These will be cheaper. Especially if you want to use a 12V supply. A linear or resistive solution would be dissipating 9.8V at 0.7 Amps = 6.86 Watts.

A better solution is a 5V or USB supply. In this case, a cheap car usb charger would work best. It does the 12V to 5V with a switching regulator, and the rest can be done with a smaller resistor. 5 - 2.2 = 2.8V * 0.7 = 1.96W. A 2 or 2.5 Watt 4 Ohm resistor will work.

As mentioned 2.2V * 0.7A = 1.54W, half of the supposed 3 watts btw.

Comment: Something inexpensive (0.72$) like this http://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2596-DC-DC-Adjustable-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Module-Power-Supply-1-23V-30V-/272420115364?hash=item3f6d8113a4:g:iIMAAOSwqu9VHR9Z + a resistor (& possibly a heatsink) should work for his single LED application.

Comment: @zef that or a dollar store car usb charger.

Comment: Maybe or maybe not ;).  Here's an interesting test of such a product:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6LdeOyV-60  It looks like it may start to punk-out after ~0.48A.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Those should be able to do 750 mA. The problem is that dollar tree uses super cheap components. They won't do 1A without an external mosfet/transistor and appropriate sense resistor, and correct inductor. that's how the mc ic works. He notes the usb cable is thin and there was weak solder joints. I've had the same circuit type and it does 725 with just 0.1V drop at the output. @zeffur

Comment: I imagine you are probably correct with your assumptions.  Interestingly, the datasheet for the MC34063A shows that it: is 87.7% efficient @ 12V input;; can be used to provide an output switch current to 1.5A; & has an output ripple of 400 mVpp.  Here's an interesting article on the affect of ripple on li-ion capacity & inpedance (skip to the conclusion section for the highlights) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030626191630808X  It makes me wonder what kind of damage such a cheap charger may cause... ;)

Comment: @zeffur switch current is double of the actual output current for the MC34063A. That's why I said 750mA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go one step above a ballast resistor (dropper resistor), you might consider an LM317 based current source. Such as the following:[image] Taken from: [LM317](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)

The following article has a down to basics explanation of an [lm317 led driver](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ccs/LM317.htm)

Comment: It will still dissipate almost 7 watts. A switching method is better.

Comment: Absolutely, the LM317 isn't any where near state of the art for LED control. However its cheap and available in a to-220 package, has thermal shutdown, and you can daisy chain more than one LED module in series. Or short the output without consequence.

Comment: Ok i found one that is from 1.2v-37 and 1.5A can i come off the output with a resister? Also were the adjust wire is how does it know it needs to back off? I dont get the adjust wire?

Comment: The connection from the adjust pin to the far side of resistor R1 is used to sense the voltage across R1. The LM317 will set the output pin at whatever voltage it needs too to maintain 1.2 volts across R1. So with the LM317 regulating 1.2 across R1 at all times, you get to set the output current as 1.2/R1.

Answer (score 0):

The 15Ω 7+ Watt resistor is correct for a single 2.vV LED and 13.5v (2.25v x 6) battery.

What is incorrect is using a single LED with a 13.5 V battery.  You should have five in series with a 3.5Ω 2-3W resistor.

But just because an LED has an I<sub>max</sub> of 700mA does not mean you can drive it with 700mA without significant thermal management. Especially an orange AlGaInP LED.

At 700mA the LEDs are going to get very hot.  When a Cree or Luxeon 3W red-orange LED exceeds 100°C, it loses about 50% (or more) of its brightness.

You may be able to drive the five LEDs with 300mA (8.2Ω 1-2W) but they will still get hot.

Somewhere there will be a happy medium with a balance between the number of five LED strings and a thermally manageable current can be found.

If efficiency is a concern like of the LED will be on when the engine is off then a CCR (constant current regulator) would be appropriate for a current of less than 350mA.  A CCR acts like a dynamic resistor and adjusts to the dynamic voltage of the LED string. An On-Semi 150-350mA CCR  [NSI50150ADT4G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NSI50150AD-D.PDF) costs under $1.